# having issues to parse array of objects in React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

1. I've got api response from mongodb
   [res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgQkW.png)
   [res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp7Gj.png)

Code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import style from './CarsListPage.module.scss';
import cars from './car-content';
import CarsList from '../components/CarsList';

const CarsListPage = () => {
  const [carsInfo, setCarsInfo] = useState({ name: 'Name', year: 2000 });

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadCarsInfo = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('/api/cars');
      const newCarsInfo = response.data;
      setCarsInfo(newCarsInfo);
      //console.log(newCarsInfo[1].name);
    };
    loadCarsInfo();
  }, []);
  //console.log(carsInfo);
  return (
    <div className={style.mainCotainer}>
      {/* {carsInfo.forEach((car) => {
        console.log(car.name);
      })} */}
      <main className={style.main}>
        {console.log(carsInfo)}
        <h1>Cars</h1>
        <div className={style.container}>
          {/* <CarsList cars={cars} style={style} /> */}
          {cars.map((car) => (
            <Link to={`/cars/${car.name}`} key={car.id}>
              {carsInfo.forEach((car) => {
                console.log(car.name);
              })}
              <div className={style.card}>
                <h3>{car.title}</h3>
                <p>{car.body_type}</p>
                <p>{car.origin}</p>
              </div>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CarsListPage;
```

p.s. if you need more code or info feel free to ask anything

I tried:

```
carsInfo.forEach((car) => {
        console.log(car.name);
      })
```

but i keep getting => 'carsInfo.forEach is not a function' issue

BUT

I need to make something like this:

```
{cars.map((car) => (
            <Link to={`/cars/${car.name}`} key={car.id}>
              {carsInfo.forEach((car) => {
                console.log(car.name);
              })}
              <div className={style.card}>
                <h3>{car.title}</h3>
                <p>{car.body_type}</p>
                <p>{car.origin}</p>
              </div>
            </Link>
          ))}
```

The code above is working but it is not API respnse it is just some data that i stored within my project as json file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your initial state contains/is an object:

```
{ name: 'Name', year: 2000 }
```

You cannot use array methods (such as forEach) on objects. I assume you wanted to have an array/list of cars?
In that case, you need to initialize your state with an array containing your initial car object:

```
[{ name: 'Name', year: 2000 }]
```

Now, you can do `forEach` or `map` or any other array method on it, even before you get results from your API endpoint.

Comment: Cheers! but out of curiosity can this issue be fixed by the parsing array of objects or something else?